# How to check item is loaded in the scene in three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, loading

I use THREE.js Loading Manager to check the object or texture is loaded .

```
var Mesh;
var TLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager);

var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {

    console.log( item, loaded, total );

};

manager.onLoad = function()
{

    console.log(Renderer.domElement.toDataURL());
}


 function renderModel(path,texture) {

            var Material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({shading: THREE.SmoothShading});
            Material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

            var Loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(manager);
            Loader.load(path,function(geometry){

                geometry.mergeVertices();
                geometry.computeFaceNormals();
                geometry.computeVertexNormals();

                TLoader.load(texture,function(texture){


                Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, Material);
                Mesh.material.map =texture;
                Scene.add(Mesh);


                });
            });
        }
```

and i just call the renderModel function in  a loop .
But the console.log(Renderer.domElement.toDataURL()) output from the manager.onload function is giving only image of the some  3d models not all the ones in the scene

I just want to get 'Renderer.domElement.toDataURL()' when all the 3d models are rendered in the scene

now only the image of 2 or 3 models are getting ,but in scene all the items are loaded.

Answer (score 2):

The renderer renders an image each frame. When the loading of all the objects is completed, the `onLoad` method of the manager is called immediately. So, the last objects were added to the scene and you retrieve the image data without giving the renderer a chance to render a new image. You need to wait for a new frame. Maybe a `timeout` with e.g. 200 milliseconds will help.

**EDIT**

You could also call the `render` method in your `onLoad`, so the renderer draws a new image before you call `console.log`.

```
manager.onLoad = function()
{
    Renderer.render( Scene, camera );
    console.log(Renderer.domElement.toDataURL());
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works . is there any way to do it without giving the timeout :)

Comment: I've got the idea to call `Renderer.render( Scene, camera );` within your `onLoad` method. See update.

Comment: Does not work for me. It only worked with a timeout as bad workaround